# Why does type hinting not pick up the method of a class that is instantiated after being passed as an argument to a function?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to play around with dependency injection and I've come across something I don't quite understand. The following code runs fine:

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, test_variable: int) -> None:
        self.test_variable = test_variable
    
    def test_method(self):
        print(self.test_variable)
        

def run_test_method(test_class: TestClass, test_variable: int):
    test_class_instance = test_class(test_variable)
    test_class_instance.test_method()
    

run_test_method(TestClass, 1)
```

However, the type hinting doesn't pick up the `test_method` within the `run_test_method` function:

[image]

If I don't pass `TestClass` into the function then the type hinting works fine:

[image]

However, this kills off me using dependency injection :(

Is the lack of type hinting suggesting that I should always be passing an instance rather than a class? So for example:

```
def run_test_method(tester: TestClass):
    tester.test_method()

tester = TestClass(1)
run_test_method(tester)
```

I've read quite a few posts that say that passing a class as an argument is fine but this seems like a big miss for type hinting so I'm suspicious!

If it's relevant I'm using VSCode with the Python, Pylance, Python Environment Manager and Python Extension Pack extensions.

Comment: Your argument is `type[TestClass]`, surely?

Comment: Well that might be the simplest answer on SO today! I didn't realise you had to encase a class in `type[]` Thanks!

Comment: if you read the doc page about type hinting .......

Comment: If you annotate it as `TestClass`, it's an *instance* of TestClass, just like how your `test_variable` is an *instance* of `int` rather than the `int` type.

Comment: @Samwise - that was a really useful comment thanks :)

Comment: @Jossy You should run a type checker (e.g. `mypy`) on your code -- it'll make the "failures" in your IDE seem less mysterious since things like providing a `Type[Foo]` where a `Foo` was expected will produce helpful error messages.  :)

Comment: Thanks @Samwise - I have Pylance as an extension in VSCode. It looks like if I up the mode my IDE will shout at me if (when) I do something stupid...